# How do I Join table with multiple id in same column?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

[image: This is my Table]

How do I apply join for this kind of table where `document_id` is stored in array. I am aware about explode function but I really dont know how to use. I do not want to use for loop but I am expecting better idea to join this table. If I have to add something then I will add.

```
$row = DB::table('service_documents')->select('service_documents.document_id', 'service_documents.service_id')->get();
    $idArr = explode(',', $row);
    dd($idArr);

    $documents = DB::table('service_documents')->select('service.name_np as serviceName',
                                                                       'documents.name_np as documentName', 'service_documents.*')
                                                              ->join('service', 'service_documents.service_id', '=', 'service.id')
                                                              ->join('documents', 'service_documents.document_id', '=', 'documents.id')
                                                              ->get();
```

This is my join query in laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution (to have a performant query) is to add a new pivot table `document_service_document` with `service_document_id` and `document_id` as fields.

Then populate that table using existing document_id field and adapt all the codes linked to that field to use the pivot table instead.

for that, and after, you can use manyToMany relation or simple join and get the results you need the easy way.

Comment: is there any solution not adding pivot table?

I am just curious about other solution. thank you for your answer

Comment: @PurushottamTiwari you could declare the field as a json type, adapt the value and use it for the join request but that will make the request take a lot of time + you will not have consistency in your data (same as your current solution)

Comment: Hmmm.. I was thinking about this solution but it will consume my time. So, I am using your first solution. Thanks mate